# How to resolve the below nested JOIN function error

Tags: ms-access

Base Data:

```
-----------------------
Date      | ID |   PL |
-----------------------
16.09.2019| 21 |    0 |
17.09.2019| 21 |    0 |
18.09.2019| 21 |    1 |
19.09.2019| 21 |    2 |
```

Expected Output:

```
-----------------------------------
Date      | ID |   PL |  ZC | TC |
-----------------------------------
16.09.2019| 21 |    0 |  2  |  4  |
17.09.2019| 21 |    0 |  2  |  4  |
18.09.2019| 21 |    1 |  2  |  4  |
19.09.2019| 21 |    2 |  2  |  4  |
```

Code is working with single JOIN function but not with the below code

```
SELECT [4G].*,Z.ZC,T.TC
FROM 4G
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT([4G].[ID]) AS ZC, [4G].[ID]
FROM 4G
WHERE [4G].[PL] =0
GROUP BY [4G].[ID])
AS Z
ON [4G].[ID] = Z.[ID]
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT([4G].[ID]) AS TC, [4G].[ID]
FROM 4G
GROUP BY [4G].[ID])
AS T
ON [4G].[ID] = T.[ID];
```

ERROR Shown is:

```
"Syntax Error(missing operator) in query expression
'[4G].[ID] = Z.[ID]
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT([4G].[ID]) AS TC, [4G].[ID]
FROM 4G
GROUP BY [4G].[ID])
AS T
ON [4G].[ID] = T.[ID]'
```

Comment: Is this even MySQL?

Comment: what do you mean with  "JOIN function but not with the below code"  .. you have error ?? show the exact error message ..  wrong result ??  show  a proper data sample your actual result and your expected  result

Comment: **Expected output**
 Date        ID PL ZC TC
16.09.2019 21 0 2 4
17.09.2019 21 0 2 4
18.09.2019 21 1 2 4
19.09.2019 21 2 2 4

Error shown is "Syntax Error(missing operator) in query expression
'[4G].[ID] = Z.[ID]
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT([4G].[ID]) AS TC, [4G].[ID]
FROM 4G
GROUP BY [4G].[ID])
AS T
ON [4G].[ID] = T.[ID]' @scaisEdge

Comment: Edit question to show error and source data and desired result as text tables, not in a comment.

Comment: Did you use Access query builder to construct SQL? Build each of the nested queries as objects then reference them in the third. If it works properly, then can copy/paste the first two statements into the third for one composite statement and delete the first two objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access requires parentheses for each pair of joined tables before another join:

```
SELECT [4G].*,Z.ZC,T.TC
FROM ([4G]
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT([4G].[ID]) AS ZC, [4G].[ID]
  FROM [4G]
  WHERE [4G].[PL] =0
  GROUP BY [4G].[ID]
) AS Z ON [4G].[ID] = Z.[ID])
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT([4G].[ID]) AS TC, [4G].[ID]
  FROM [4G] 
  GROUP BY [4G].[ID]
) AS T ON [4G].[ID] = T.[ID];
```

Results:

```
Date        ID  PL  ZC  TC
16/9/2019   21  0   2   4
17/9/2019   21  0   2   4
18/9/2019   21  1   2   4
19/9/2019   21  2   2   4
```